# A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I have Created Rest Api that will Save Student Data To DB.
And Student Roll No will be the Primary Key, I don't Want it to be Auto-Generated,
So that's why i Haven't given any Generation Strategy.

Student Can Have Many Pens, So there is `One To Many Mapping`.
Whenever i try to save the data to db i get **error** `A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session.`.

**i know that there can be only one object in the Session per primary key**

**DAO LAYER**

```
    @Autowired
        private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void saveStudent(Students student) {
  // here i am saving data
            entityManager.persist(student);
        }
```

Student Pojo  :

```
    @Entity
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Table(name = "list_of_students")
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class Students implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -163504605143278308L;

        @Column(name = "student_name")
        private String name;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "student_roll_no")
        private Long rollNo;

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "student", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
        private Set<Pen> pens = new HashSet<Pen>();

        @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable(name = "student_courses", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "student_roll_no") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "course_id") })
        private Set<Courses> listOfCourses = new HashSet<Courses>();

    }
```

Pen Pojo:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Table(name = "pens")
public class Pen {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "pen_color",unique=true,columnDefinition="VARCHAR(64)")
    private String color;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade =CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="student_roll_no")
    private Students student;
}
```

i have tried doing this mentioned below: by doing this i don't get any error,
but no data is saved to `pens Table`
in pens table i want student roll no mapped to pen color.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "student", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
    private Set<Pen> pens = new HashSet<Pen>();
```

**REST CONTROLLER**

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Add Student")
@RequestMapping(value = "add/Student", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public void addStudentData(@Valid @RequestBody Students student) {

    service.save(student);

}
```

**POSTMAN REQUEST**

URL : http://localhost:8080/add/Student

```
{
    "name": "Ashish Upadhyay",
    "rollNo": "1",
    "pens": [{
        "color": "RED",
        "student":{
            "rollNo":"1"
        }
    }],
    "listOfCourses": [{
            "courseName": "Data Structures",
            "courseId": 1
        },
        {
            "courseName": "Alogrithms",
            "courseId": 2
        },
        {
            "courseName": "Pysical Education",
            "courseId": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The problem is in the code that you didn't show, which gets the JSON and saves data in the database.

Comment: @JBNizet am savinfg the data here **entityManager.persist(student);**

Comment: And the problem is what the `student`variable contains. My guess being that it contains a Student which has a Pen which has another Student with the same ID.

Comment: @JBNizet added the full Snippet now, please have a look

Comment: @JBNizet yes pen (POJO ) has another Student as i want to map pen to Student as well

Comment: It shouldn't have another student. It should have **the same** student. You have two different Student objects, the one you save, and the one references by the pen. It should be the same object. And your JSON shouldn't have a student field under pens. Of course they are the pens of the student being sent. No need to say that in the JSON.

Comment: @JBNizet if i don't provide student field in pen, then no data will be saved in pen table. And how to i do this **You have two different Student objects, the one you save, and the one references by the pen. It should be the same object.**

Comment: no data will be saved in pen *if you don't write the code necessary to do it*. You need to  write the necessary code: `pen.setStudent(student)`